# Slow Oracle Update Compared to Select

Tags: sql, oracle

We're experiencing very slow performance updating a table in Oracle 9i when a Select statement to return the same rows takes less than 20 seconds. When I say very slow, we have left it running overnight and it still did not finish.

I've simplified the tables and columns to illustrate the problem and to hide the names as they are tables used in a third-party app (however, the data is normally maintained in-house and support calls are expensive). Even in this simple example, the update didn't finish after running for over 4 hours.

```
CREATE TABLE lookup 
(
  lookup_key       NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY KEY, 
  lookup_name      VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

There are c. 34,000 rows in this table

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
  product_key     NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  product_val     NUMBER(10,0)
);
```

There are c. 14.5 million rows in this table

The Select statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM lookup
WHERE lookup_name <> 'Redundant'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products
where product_val = lookup_key);
```

The Update statement is:

```
UPDATE lookup 
SET lookup_name = 'Redundant'
WHERE lookup_name <> 'Redundant'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products
WHERE product_val = lookup_key);
```

The execution plan is the same between the 2 both in this trivial example and the real world one. All statistics are up to date.

I guess we could do it in PL/SQL but surely it should be quick enough to update all the rows in lookup, that aren't in the product table, to 'Redundant' in SQL? Any ideas or advice gratefully received thanks.

Comment: Updating 34,000 rows should not take that long.  You either have locks that are preventing the query from completing or triggers that take a long, long time.  Start with updating a single row in `lookup` to see how long that takes.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It takes 4.5 seconds to update one record, 45 seconds to update 10, 475 seconds to update 100 so I suppose extrapolating that would result in its taking hours. There are no triggers on that table and on the database we're using we are the only user logged on.

Comment: If we just update rows without reference to the NOT Exists clause then it takes 0.39 seconds to update every row on the table where lookup_name <> 'Redundant' i.e.

UPDATE lookup 
SET lookup_name = 'Redundant'
WHERE lookup_name <> 'Redundant'

Comment: Should that not be: SELECT 1 FROM products
WHERE product_**KEY** = lookup_key  ?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified  products. product_val is a foreign key that refers to lookup.product_key

Comment: Post your execution plan. You should see `HASH JOIN ANTI`

Answer (score 2):

Here is your sample setup

```
CREATE TABLE lookup 
as select 
rownum lookup_key, 'xxxxx'||rownum as lookup_name
from dual connect by level <= 34000;

CREATE TABLE products 
as 
with a as
(select rownum i 
from dual connect by level <= 1450000),
b as 
(select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ rownum j 
from dual connect by level <= 10)
select 
i*10 + j + 34000 product_key,  i*10 + j + 34000 as product_val
from a cross join b;
```

The update gives this execution plan - note the `HASH JOIN ANTI` this is a effectiv plan for such a query. If you see something else (e..g `FILTER`) this is a problem, you perform the `FULL TABLE SCAN` *once for each updatetd row*.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |          | 32957 |  1609K|   554   (3)| 00:00:10 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN ANTI    |          | 32957 |  1609K|   554   (3)| 00:00:10 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| LOOKUP   | 32957 |  1190K|    19   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| PRODUCTS |  1320K|    16M|   530   (2)| 00:00:10 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("PRODUCT_VAL"="LOOKUP_KEY")
   2 - filter("LOOKUP_NAME"<>'Redundant')
```

And here the update taking **less than 5 seconds to update all rows of the lookup table**

```
SQL> UPDATE lookup
  2  SET lookup_name = 'Redundant'
  3  WHERE lookup_name <> 'Redundant'
  4  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products
  5  WHERE product_val = lookup_key);

34000 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:04.97
```

Note that this is a **defensive strategy** if you **expect lots of updates**. The total cost of the update is comparable to a one `FULL TABLE SCAN`on the big table.

In case you **expects a small number of updates** you may profit from the index proposed in other answer.

```
 create index products_idx on products(PRODUCT_VAL);
```

The execution plan changes to `NESTED LOOPS ANTI`:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT    |              |     1 |    32 |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE             | LOOKUP       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS ANTI |              |     1 |    32 |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| LOOKUP       |     1 |    19 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN | PRODUCTS_IDX |    14M|   178M|     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter("LOOKUP_NAME"<>'Redundant')
   4 - access("PRODUCT_VAL"="LOOKUP_KEY")
```

The update of one row goes instantly ...

```
SQL> UPDATE lookup
  2  SET lookup_name = 'Redundant'
  3  WHERE lookup_name <> 'Redundant'
  4  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products
  5  WHERE product_val = lookup_key);

1 row updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.13
```

... but the elapsed time will lineary increase with the numer of updated rows (and for few thousends the cost will increase the cost of the FTS in the previous execution plan.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts but here there are no matches between the 2 tables? The product_val is looked up against the lookup_key so, as there are over 14 million rows, there are necessarily thousands of instances of each product_val. Thanks.

Comment: @pinksalmon feel free to adapt the sample setup. I approached the worst case. If there is no match the NOT EXISTS must scan the whole table and all rows are updated.

Answer (score 1):

For test purpose I would do:

```
create table lookup2 as select * from lookup
```

And run your update.

```
UPDATE lookup2 
SET lookup_name = 'Redundant'
WHERE lookup_name <> 'Redundant'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products
WHERE product_val = lookup_key);
```

If that goes fast it means slow down is due to index rebuild on lookup_name, triggers, chained rows or other problems tablespace. If that goes slow it means problem is query itself or there are problems with physical disk performance (what is hard to believe with 34k rows).

I also wonder how this corellated not exists works here. maybe try:

```
create table tmp as
SELECT lookup_key FROM lookup
WHERE lookup_name <> 'Redundant'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products
where product_val = lookup_key);

merge into lookup l
using (select * from tmp) t
on (l.lookup_key = t.lookup_key)
when matched then update set lookup_name = 'Redundant'
WHERE lookup_name <> 'Redundant';

drop table tmp;
```

Or the select was fast only for first 100 rows not all of them?

Comment: Thanks for replying. The Select was fast for ALL rows. I'll have a look at your suggestions thanks.

Comment: @PinkSalmon - to clarify Kacper's last question: how do you run your queries? A front-end like Toad may show you the first 100 rows before it completes the entire SELECT query. I assume you are confirming that the query finished working and reported "selected 122032 rows in 20 seconds" or something like that; 20 seconds wasn't the interval until something FIRST showed up on your monitor.

Comment: SQL Developer. 20 seconds is the time to return ALL the rows to the screen i.e. CTRL+End to the end of the Result Set

Comment: @Kacper In the first suggestion this ran for 15 minutes so I killed this. In the second suggestion the tmp table was created in less than 10 seconds and the Merge ran in less than a second (albeit I had to add a WHEN NOT MATCHED clause, which seems to be mandatory in 9i).

I'm not sure what this is telling me though to be completely honest and why the original Update is so slow.

Comment: Do you have an index on PRODUCT_VAL?

Comment: @BobC No and hadn't tried adding one in this simplified scenario as the original third-party tables don't have an index on this column (and we aren't allowed to change their tables). However, adding one does make the update sub-second. Should have tried this before but think I got bogged down in trying to understand the difference between the Select and the Update on the actual tables. Thanks.

Comment: @PinkSalmon. OK, let me make that comment an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an index to `PRODUCT_VAL` to avoid scanning the `PRODUCTS` table for each `LOOKUP`

Comment: Whilst I can do this in my example, I can't do that on the actual tables as we are not allowed to alter them. I guess I'm still struggling to understand why the Select would be so quick when the Update takes forever. Thanks.

Comment: @PinkSalmon Because you are in effect running the select for each row that you want to update.

Comment: @PinkSalmon I'm not sure why you would ask for help here if you can't make changes !

Comment: We are only unable to change the tables. The SQL is a one-off update to the data on the lookup table to release values for re-use.

Comment: @BobC this will help (to avoid one FTS per updated row), but 34K index access in a nested loop will still take a long time.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber   Yup 34k index access would. But I don't think he is doing that many, otherwise his update would not be subsecond.

Comment: Pls read above *It takes 4.5 seconds to update one record,*; on a good HW a FTS on the big table takes 5 secs.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Yes, I realize that; but travel above, one he  added the correct index, the update was sub second.

Comment: @BobC you are right - I added this consideration in my answer. Sorry for the last comment, my premise was there will by a lange number of upadates, which is not necessary true...